# Problem about moving sides of triangle

Tags: calculus, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

Imagine a triangle XOY which sides lie on x-axis and y-axis with hypotenuse XY of length 5 m.

Suppose the point X moves away from the (0,0) along x-axis with speed = 1 m per second. What speed the point Y will have when length of OX will be 3 m?

---

If OX = 3, then OY = $\sqrt{5^2 - 3^2} = 4$. Unfortunately, this is all I did. Please, give a hint how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

$$OX^2+OY^2=5^2\implies 2OX\cdot\frac{d(OX)}{dt}+2OY\cdot\frac{d(OY)}{dt}=0$$

$$\implies OX\cdot\frac{d(OX)}{dt}+\sqrt{25-OX^2}\cdot\frac{d(OY)}{dt}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

You've found that $OY = \sqrt{5^2 - OX^2}$. Now, given $OX$ and $OX'$ you need to find $OY'$.

Comment: via differentiation of composite function? $OY' = 1/(2\cdot 4) \times (-2 OX') = -1/4$

Comment: right, but you made an error while differentiating. $(OX^2)' = 2 \cdot OX \cdot OX'$.